# Printing wchar_t produces strange results

Tags: c++

I have a

```
const wchar_t* statusMsg = restResponse.reason_phrase().c_str();
```

I use two ways to print them.

```
std::wcout << "Status Msg : " << *statusMsg << *(statusMsg + 1) << std::endl;

std::wcout << "Status Msg : " << statusMsg;
```

The actual output should be `OK`. The first statement prints `OK` whereas, the second one just prints `O`. What is wrong here?

Additionally, I have this code while using Casablanca Rest SDK.

Comment: Replaced `restResponse.reason_phrase().c_str()` with `L"OK"` and it all worked for me, so I'd be curious as to what else your code is doing. How are you successfully implicitly converting a `c_str()` here? What is the real return value of a `restResponse.reason_phrase().c_str()`?

Comment: In debugging, when I point the cursor at `statusMsg` variable, I can see `L"OK"`. But, output for me is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that function `restResponse.reason_phrase()` returns a temporary object of type `std::wstring` In this case after this statement the temporary object will be deleted and pointer `statusMsg` will be invalid.

Instead of the pointer you should define an object of type `std::wstring` that will be initialized by the return value of the function and apply member function `c_str` to this object.

Otherwise the program has undefined behaviour.